# Unit test Angular with Jasmine and Karma, Error:Can't bind to 'xxx' since it isn't a known property of 'xxxxxx'.

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with an unit test in angular 5 with Jasmine and Karma.

The error is: "Can't bind to 'fruits' since it isn't a known property of 'my-component2'".

The unit test code is:

src/app/components/my-component1/my-component1.component.spec.ts:

```js
import { TestBed, inject, ComponentFixture, async} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { Post } from '../../models/post.model';

import { MyComponent1Component } from './my-component1.component';
import { MyService1Service } from '../../services/my-service1.service';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient,HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import {fruit} from '../../Models/fruit';


fdescribe('MyComponent1Component', () => {
  let component: MyComponent1Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent1Component>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent1Component ],
      imports: [],
      providers: [MyService1Service, HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpTestingController]
    })

    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent1Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And these are the code of my components:

src/app/components/my-component1/my-component1.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService1Service} from '../../services/my-service1.service';
import {fruit} from '../../Models/fruit';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component1',
  templateUrl: './my-component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component1.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _MyService1Service: MyService1Service) { }

  public fruit= new fruit();

  public fruits: fruit[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this._MyService1Service.getPost().subscribe(
        result => {
              console.log(result);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );

    this.fruit.name = 'apple';
    this.fruits.push(this.fruit);
  }
}
```

src/app/components/my-component1/my-component1.component.html:

```html
 <p>
      my-component1 works!
    </p>

    <my-component2 [fruits]=fruits></my-component2>
```

src/app/components/my-component2/my-component2.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {fruit} from '../../Models/fruit';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component2',
  templateUrl: './my-component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component2.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent2Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() fruits: fruit[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

src/app/components/my-component2/my-component2.component.html:

```html
<p>
  my-component2 works!
</p>
```

It is a dummy project, can anybody help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to add your second component when creating your testing module as that module is part of component 1. If you don't the module won't have my-component2 and the input will be invalid.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent1Component, MyComponent2Component ],
      imports: [],
      providers: [MyService1Service, HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpTestingController]
    })
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I can run the tests in Karma with Chrome. However when I switch to headless Chrome, it fails to load my app code for whatever reason.

Answer (score 9):

For Some this might help -  some times it may just be the specific module that might be missing

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule(
{
declarations: [TestComponent],
imports: [<Specific_module>],
}
```